# Use foreach to simplify tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz diagram but I think it should be simplified with foreach loop. I have try many times but I still can not get right answer!

My code as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\def\r{5pt}
\def\dy{.5cm}
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-]
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [c,label=right:$C_0$] (C0) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C0,label=right:$C_1$] (C1) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C1,label=right:$C_2$] (C2) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C2,label=right:$C_3$] (C3) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C3,label=right:$C_4$] (C4) {};

\node [c,right=\dy of C1,label=right:$C_6$] (C6) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C6,label=right:$C_7$] (C7) {};
\node [c,above=\dy of C7,label=right:$C_8$] (C8) {};

\draw [line] (C0) -- (C1);
\draw [line] (C1) -- (C2);
\draw [line] (C2) -- (C3);
\draw [line] (C3) -- (C4);

\draw [line] (C0) -- (C6);
\draw [line] (C6) -- (C7);
\draw [line] (C7) -- (C8);
\draw [line] (C8) -- (C4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: A matrix of nodes might also help :)

Comment: See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223384/tikz-chain-nominate-node-location/223394#223394 for a PSTricks solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\def\r{5pt}
\def\dy{.5cm}
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center]
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)
    node [c,label=right:$C_0$] (C0) {}
    foreach \i in {1,...,4}
      {
        -- ++(0,\dy+\r) node (C\i) [c,label=right:$C_\i$] {}
      };
  \draw (C1) ++(\dy+\r,0)
    node (C6) [c,label=right:$C_6$] {}
    foreach \i in {7,8}
      {
        -- ++(0,\dy+\r) node (C\i) [c,label=right:$C_\i$] {}
      }
    -- (C4)
    (C0) -- (C6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But you might also look at the `chains` library.

Comment: Thanks, one minor issue is when I remove the fill in the circle, I can see the line has draw on the circle also. I wish it only connect from circle border to border but not passthrough the circle.

Comment: @Beatlej I just did it the easiest way given the picture. You can change it to connect from specific anchors. However, I really think you should look at the chains library and/or the matrix of nodes suggested in the comments. These make it really easy to arrange nodes (matrix) and connect them (chains) in a grid-type layout. It will make your life much easier, I think.

Answer (score 3):

This a solution with a `matrix of math nodes` and no `chains`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{sha/.style={draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,inner sep=.2pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes, nodes={sha}, column sep=6mm, row sep=4mm]
{
C_3\\
C_2 & C_5\\
C_1 & C_4\\
C_0\\
};

\foreach \i/\j in {4/3,3/2,2/1}
    \draw [-latex] (C-\i-1)--(C-\j-1);

\draw [-latex] (C-4-1)--(C-3-2);
\draw [-latex]  (C-3-2)--(C-2-2);
\draw [-latex]  (C-2-2)--(C-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,one question is if I need to add more nodes later, than previous ones maybe need to tweak also since matrix maybe different.

Answer (score 3):

### *This is the answer you are looking for!* ;-)

The other answers use chains, multiple for loops and other strange stuff.
What you need is a **remember your parent** with an **initial value of zero**. 
Luckily this is already built into PGF, which allows this nice, condense lump of code.

```
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-]
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={.5cm}]          
\node [c,label=right:$C_0$] (C0) {};                       %% Initial Node
\foreach \l/\r %
[remember=\l as \lp (initially 0), remember=\r as \rp (initially 0)] %
in {1/4,2/5,3/6} {                                         %% <- node index for left/right
    \node [c,above=of C\lp,label=right:$C_\l$] (C\l) {};   %% place left node above its parent
    \node [c,right=of C\l,label=right:$C_\r$] (C\r) {};    %% place right node next to left one
    \draw[line] (C\lp) -- (C\l);                           %% draw lines to parents
    \draw[line] (C\rp) -- (C\r);
}
\node [c,above=of C3,label=right:$C_4$] (C4) {};           %% finish manually with node C4
\draw[line] (C3) -- (C4);
\draw[line] (C6) -- (C4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I used

- `l` as `left node`
- `lp` as `left parent`
- `r` as `right node`
- `rp` as `right parent`

The result looks exactly like your image, so I don't repeat it here. Thanks for the question, I learned a lot while looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One example using chain library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 6mm,
    every join/.style={->},>=latex,
    start chain=M going above]

\node[sha] (C0) {$C_{0}$};
% sub branch
\begin{scope}[start branch=B1 going above right]
  \node[sha] (C4) {$C_{4}$};
  \foreach \i in {5} {
    \node[sha,on chain=going above] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\end{scope}
% main branch
\foreach \i in {1,...,2} {
  \node [sha,on chain=going above] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
}
% merge node
\node [sha,on chain,join=with M/B1-end] {$C_{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

But I prefer to C4 and C5 at the same level, but now it's not. Still not clear about how to make it align with C4.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it this way after summary so many good answers!

Use two branches M0 and M1, then merge it together.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 6mm,
    every join/.style={->},>=latex,
    start chain=M0 going above,
    start chain=M1 going above,
    ]
  % chain M0 for left part
  \foreach \i in {0,...,2} {
    \node [sha,on chain=M0] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
  % chain M1 for right part
  \foreach \i in {4,5} {
    \ifnum\i=4
      \node[sha,on chain=M1,right=of C1,join=with C0] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
    \else
      \node[sha,on chain=M1] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
    \fi       
  }
  % merge M0 and M1-end to C3
  \node [sha,on chain=M0,join=with M1-end] (C3) {$C_{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Or remove the if statement to save more lines:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 6mm,
    every join/.style={->},>=latex,
    start chain=M0 going above,
    start chain=M1 going above,
    ]
  % chain M0 for left part
  \foreach \i in {0,...,2} {
    \node [sha,on chain=M0] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
  % chain M1 for right part
  \node[sha,on chain=M1,right=of C1,join=with C0] (C4) {$C_{4}$};
  \foreach \i in {5} {
      \node[sha,on chain=M1] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};       
  }
  % merge M0 and M1-end to C3
  \node [sha,on chain=M0,join=with M1-end] (C3) {$C_{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 3 lines of TikZ code (9 total lines):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,4) -- (1,3) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4,6,7,8}
      \node[circle,fill,label=right:$C_\i$] at ({div(\i,5)}, {mod(\i,5)}){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with TikZ graph library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout,grow=up,nodes={draw,thick,fill=blue!20,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  { "$C_0$" -> {"$C_4$" -> "$C_5$", "$C_1$" -> "$C_2$"} -> "$C_3$" };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Interesting code -:). so simple, but if I have multiple such block connected together, is it so easy?

Comment: @HenriMenke in this particular example, the `quotes` library isn't necessary. If `math nodes` is given as an argument to the `\graph` command then it is possible to specify the graph like this: `C_0 -> {C_4 -> C_5, C_1 -> C_2} -> C_3`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got my finally result after reading so many great answers!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=white,opacity=.8,on chain,join,minimum size=14pt,inner sep=.2pt]
\tikzstyle{curly}=[gray,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}]

\begin{document}
\def\dx{.8cm}
\def\dy{.05cm}
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=\dy and \dx,
    every join/.style={-},>=latex,
    start chain=M0 going above,
    start chain=M1 going above,
    start chain=M2 going above,
    start chain=M3 going above,
    ]

  % chain M0
  \foreach \i in {0,...,12} {
    \ifnum\i>8
      \node [sha,on chain=M0,fill=green!20] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
    \else
      \node [sha,on chain=M0] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
    \fi
  }
  % chain M1
  \node[sha,on chain=M1,right=\dx of C1,join=with C0] (C13) {$C_{13}$};
  \foreach \i in {14,15} {
      \node[sha,on chain=M1] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};       
  }
  % chain M2
  \node[sha,on chain=M2,left=\dx of C5,join=with C4] (C16) {$C_{16}$};
  \foreach \i in {17,...,18} {
      \node[sha,on chain=M2] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};       
  }
  % chain M3
  \node[sha,on chain=M3,fill=green!20,right=2*\dx of C7,join=with C4] (C19) {$C_{19}$};
  \foreach \i in {20,...,22} {
      \node[sha,on chain=M3,fill=green!20] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};       
  }
  % decoration
  \draw[-latex] foreach \i/\j in {15/4,18/8}{(C\i) edge (C\j)};
  \draw [curly] (C19.west) -- (C22.west) 
    node [black,midway,xshift=-10pt] (A1) {\footnotesize $\delta$};
  \draw [curly] (C12.east) -- (C9.east) 
    node [black,midway,xshift=10pt] (A2) {\footnotesize $\delta$};
  \draw [->,>=latex,red!50] (A1)  to [out=90,in=0] 
    node [black,midway,sloped,midway,above] {git\ rebase} (A2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]