# TikZ chain nominate node location

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I want to nominate node C4 at right of C1. so I have to define C1 before create C4.

Below code seems has one extra line from C0 to C3.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 6mm,
    every join/.style={->},>=latex,
    start chain=M going above]

\node[sha] (C0) {$C_{0}$};
% main branch
\begin{scope}[start branch=B0 going above]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,2} {
    \node [sha] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[start branch=B1 going above]
  \node[sha,right=of C1,join=with C0] (C4) {$C_{4}$};
  \foreach \i in {5,6} {
    \node[sha] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\end{scope}

\node [sha,join=with M/B0-end,join=with M/B1-end,above=of C2] {$C_{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Maybe I need to remove one branch but not sure how to do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want? You need to tell `B1 branch` that `C3` is at left of `C6`, same as what you did for `C4`, saying that `C4` is at right of `C1`. Note that `C3` should be generated by `B0 branch`, which was not in the OP.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzstyle{sha}=[draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 6mm,
    every join/.style={->},>=latex,
    start chain=M going above]

\node[sha] (C0) {$C_{0}$};
% main branch
\begin{scope}[start branch=B0 going above]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,3} {
    \node [sha] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[start branch=B1 going above]
  \node[sha,right=of C1,join=with C0] (C4) {$C_{4}$};
  \foreach \i in {5,6} {
  \node[sha] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
  \node[sha,left=of C6] (C3) {$C_{3}$};  % same as C4, telling B1 that it is located right of C1
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way of organising things

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzset{sha/.style={draw,circle,fill=green!20,opacity=.8,on chain,join,inner sep=.2pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going above,
start chain=2 going above,
node distance=4mm and 6mm,
every join/.style={->},>=latex,
]
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
    \node [sha,on chain=1,join] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\node [sha,on chain=2,right = of C1,join = with C0]  {C4};

\foreach \i in {5,6} {
    \node[sha,on chain=2,join] (C\i) {$C_{\i}$};
  }
\draw[->] (C6) -- (C3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, use two chain resolve this issue perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

In 3 lines of TikZ code (9 total lines):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,6}
      \node[draw,circle,fill=green!21] (C\i) at ({div(\i,4)}, {div(\i,4)+mod(\i,4)}) {$C_\i$};
    \draw[-latex] foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3,0/4,4/5,5/6,6/3}{(C\i) edge (C\j)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1.9,4.6)
  \pnodes{P}(0.35,0.35)(0.35,1.65)(0.35,2.95)(0.35,4.25)(1.65,1.65)(1.65,2.95)(1.65,4.25)
  \multido{\i = 0+1}{7}{%
    \psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = green!20, opacity = 0.8}
    \cnode(P\i){0.35}{C\i}
    \rput(C\i){$C_{\i}$}}
  \psset{arrows = ->}
  \ncline{C0}{C1}
  \ncline{C1}{C2}
  \ncline{C2}{C3}
  \ncline{C0}{C4}
  \ncline{C4}{C5}
  \ncline{C5}{C6}
  \ncline{C6}{C3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

Here is a fully 'automated' version where all you have to do is choose the values of the parameters and the drawing will then be adjusted accordingly (also, instead of drawing nodes, circles are drawn):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}
\def\PScircle(#1,#2)#3{%
  \pscircle[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = green!20, opacity = 0.8](#1,#2){\radius}
  \rput(#1,#2){#3}}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\const#1#2{\calc{(#1)*\separation+(#2)*\radius}}

% parameters
\def\height{4}
\def\separation{1.3}
\def\radius{0.35}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\const{1}{2},\const{\height-1}{2})
  \PScircle(\radius,\radius){$C_{0}$}
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\calc{\height-1}}{%
    \PScircle(\radius,\const{\i}{1}){$C_{\i}$}
    \PScircle(\const{1}{1},\const{\i}{1}){$C_{\calc{\i+\height-1}}$}}
  \psset{arrows = ->}
  \psline(\radius,\const{0}{2})(\radius,\separation)
  \psline(\const{0}{1+1/sqrt(2)},\const{0}{1+1/sqrt(2)})%
         (\const{1}{1-1/sqrt(2)},\const{1}{1-1/sqrt(2)})
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\calc{\height-2}}{%
    \psline(\radius,\const{\i}{2})(\radius,\const{\i+1}{0})
    \psline(\const{1}{1},\const{\i}{2})(\const{1}{1},\const{\i+1}{0})}
  \psline(\separation,\const{\height-1}{1})(\const{0}{2},\const{\height-1}{1})
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```